# How use the word "surge" properly?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Would it be correct to use the word 'surge' at the very end of a sentence?

For instance:

X has made Y surge.

Or would you rather say

X surged Y?

Comment: If Y is a numerical quantity, you can say that something made it surge, or caused a surge in it (using _surge_ as a noun) - but not 'surged it', because _to surge_ is intransitive.

Comment: Okay: The play's new costumes have made its popularity surge.

Comment: I think the 2 most popular uses of surge are: 1) There was a power surge at the NY power plant 2) The candidate's popularity surged at the last moment, so she was elected

Answer (score 1):

Generally the former is going to be correct, and the latter incorrect; you wouldn't normally use the verb *surged* with an object in that way. So examples:

> Sanctions on Russia(x) have made oil prices(y) surge.

> A sudden drop in demand(x) can make electrical current(y) surge.

You can use *surged*, but normally with a complement rather than an object.

> The crowd(x) surged forward.